# Will inclusion of webkit in Flex AIR app cause rejection by Mac App Store?

Tags: macos, apache-flex, air

I have found one report (on www.pigsels.com) that inclusion of the webkit plugin will result in rejection of a Flex AIR app that has been submitted to the Mac App Store.

Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found additional discussion about webkit that confirms rejection by the Mac App Store, albeit focusing on QTWebKit. I think it is germane.

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.user/167

It would appear that the AIR webkit is a different build and is not acceptable.